# Why 2 parallel tasks have same pid?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I just configured `airflow.cfg` to work with `LocalExecutor`:

```
    executor = LocalExecutor
    sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost:5432/airflow
    sql_engine_encoding = utf-8
```

after initializing the DB , I run the following DAG:

```
with DAG(dag_id='a_example_parallel_v', schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2),) as dag:

    def task1_func(ti):
        print(f"pid: ({[os.getgid()]}task1: print from task 1")

    def task2_func(ti):
        print(f"pid: ({[os.getgid()]}task1: print from task 2")

    def task3_func(ti):
        print(f"pid: ({[os.getgid()]}task1: print from task 3")

    def task4_func(ti):
        print(f"pid: ({[os.getgid()]}task1: print from task 4")


    task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1', python_callable=task1_func, provide_context=True)
    task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2', python_callable=task2_func, provide_context=True)
    task3 = PythonOperator(task_id='task3', python_callable=task3_func, provide_context=True)
    task4 = PythonOperator(task_id='task4', python_callable=task4_func, provide_context=True)

task1 >> task2
task1 >> task3
task2 >> task4
task3 >> task4
```

[image]

- I checked the logs of task 2 & task 3 and they printed the same PID.
- If task 2 & task 3 have same PID, it means that they are not running in parallel.

How can I configure airflow, in order that task 2 and task 3 run in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow has setting in `airflow.cfg`:

[`execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/40028f3ea3e78a9cf0db9de6b16fa67fa730dd7a/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L154) - Should tasks be executed via forking of the parent process ("False", the speedier option) or by spawning a new python process ("True" slow, but means plugin changes picked up by tasks straight away)

Reasoning for this can be found in the [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11327) that added the feature:
Spawning a whole new python process and then re-loading all of Airflow
is expensive. All though this time fades to insignificance for long
running tasks, this delay gives a "bad" experience for new users when
they are just trying out Airflow for the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. How do I know that indeed the 2 tasks (task 2 and task 3) run in parallel and airflow.cfg is correct for this parallel run ?

Comment: I changed execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter to True, init the DB and rerun the scheduler, and still same results (task 2 and task 2 have same PID).

Comment: I believe you need `getpid()` not `getgid()`?

Comment: my mistake - I had to use getpid()